Formulas has an "@" between them when i use xlsx writer to create a excel sheet in python
im working on a project in python where i have to collect some filtered date from google sheets and create a new .xlsx file, the problem is that one of the columns on google sheets, has a image formula on it, and i have to translate-it to portuguese so my excel can read-it, but when i create the new .xlsx file and open it, the formula doesn't work because it has a "@" between the equals sign and the rest of the formula, like this: "=@IMAGE("URL")"
since my excel is in portuguese, the "=IMAGE" formula have to be translated to "=IMAGEM" to be able to work, i used .replace and it worked just fine. i read some questions here and it seems that the problem might be on the writing part, some people managed to do it using write_array_formula, others, using just write, but i tried all of this and nothing, i even tried extracting only the link part and rebuilt the formula manualy, but, now, instead of a "@" it has curly brackets between it, like this:excel print
it looks like it is interpreting the curly brackets that i used in python with fString, but im not sure, im sending the code here, hope someone could help me hahaWritting function

Never use portuguese Excel, but pretty sure '=_xlfn.IMAGE("URL")' works: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later

unfortunaly it didnt worked :( stills has the @ after the Equals sign

According to this : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#non-us-excel-functions-and-syntax I think all formulas must be written in US format.

I use English Excel and I use below code:
import pandas as pd

with pd.ExcelWriter('Temp.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=_xlfn.IMAGE("https://i.sstatic.net/lEDnT49F.png")')

IMAGE function is applied properly (no @ at front). (I got "BLOCKED" error because I am on Mac and I need to something extra to grant access to excel file or something...)

